# JavaFX CustomMenuItem CheckBox text invisible/undrendered until mouseover

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm writing a JavaFX program as a learning exercise. I'm attempting to add a `CustomMenuItem` with a `CheckBox` child `Node`, to a `Menu` (I want to take advantage of `CustomMenuItem.setHideOnClick()`). On run, the menu populates with the checkbox fine... but the text is invisible/unrendered until mouseover. No other node type does this. Here's a bit of example code, which my program follows:

example.fxml

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="ExampleController">
  <MenuBar AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <Menu ext="Menu" fx:id="menu">
      <items>
        <CustomMenuItem hideOnClick="false">
          <content>
            <CheckBox text="Click Me" />
          </content>
        </CustomMenuItem>
      </items>
    </Menu>
  </MenuBar>
</AnchorPane>
```

I've also tried adding CustomMenuItem to the Menu via the controller:

```
menu.getItems().add(new CustomMenuItem(new CheckBox("Click Me")));
```

with the same result - "Click Me" only appears next to the checkbox on mouseover. I wasn't able to find any other posts with the same problem, and I haven't found anything in the javadocs for the involved classes that might point to what's going on.

I am stumped :(

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. Setting `textFill` was the solution for me:

```
<CheckBox text="Click Me" textFill="#000000"/>
```